# What's the difference between git add '*.txt' and git add *.txt?

Tags: git, github

I was just processing git course https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 at code school and was confused by different behaviour of git add '*.txt' and git add *.txt.

String without quoted did not add everything. Same for git rm. Why does it work this way? Or it's just web version specific?

Comment: It looks like the usual file name quotation in a (Linux) shell (e. g. bash).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Wildcards inside quotes"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67761/7490)",  globbing doesn't work in either single- or double-quotes.

> Fileglobs (e.g. `*.c`) can be given to add all matching files

- Without quotes, globbing would be done by the shell in the current folder.
- With quotes, it prevents globbing by the shell, and allows Git (contrary to my initial answer) to process the **[pathspec](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/git-add.txt#L52-L63)** "`*.txt`" accross the all worktree (and not just the current folder).

You can see examples in [`t/t4010-diff-pathspec.sh#L53-L56`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2635c2b8bfc9aec07b7f023d8e3b3d02df715344/t/t4010-diff-pathspec.sh#L53-L56)

---

[Commit 8300016](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8300016e0ab6959c4b45f64ec585832726430fc7) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster) adds another way to prevent file globbing, plus some explanation:

> ### `gitcli`: contrast wildcard given to shell and to git
>
> People who are not used to working with shell may intellectually understand how the command line argument is massaged by the shell but still have a hard time visualizing the difference between letting the shell expand fileglobs and having Git see the fileglob to use as a pathspec.
>
> Many commands allow wildcards in paths, but you need to protect
>      them from getting globbed by the shell.  These two mean different
>      things:

```
--------------------------------
$ git checkout -- *.c
$ git checkout -- \*.c
--------------------------------
```

> - The former lets your shell expand the fileglob, and you are asking
>     the dot-C files in your working tree to be overwritten with the version
>     in the index.
> - The latter passes the `*.c` to Git, and you are asking
>     the paths in the index that match the pattern to be checked out to your
>     working tree.

Comment: Excellent! So, `git add '*.txt'` and `git add \*.txt` will do the same job.

Comment: @avasin yes, anything preventing globbing by the shell.